# How do I make the Popover hide when I mouseleave the element but mouseenter the popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the Html for the popover, which is used to display a summary of a user profile when someone hover's over the profile thumbnail.

```
                      <div class="user-avatar" style="background-image: url({{          $chat->from->small_avatar }}); " data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-content="<div class='group-chat-popover'>
                      <div class='popover-header'>
                        <div class='chat-avatar' style='background-image:url({{ $chat->from->small_avatar }})'></div>
                        <div class='header-description'>
                          <p class='user-name'>{{ $chat->from->full_name }}</p>
                          <p class='user-bio'>{{ $chat->from->about }}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='user-activity'>
                        <div class='activity'>
                          <p class='activity-category'>Reputation</p>
                            <p class='activity-count'>{{ $chat->from->total_points }}</p></div>
                        <div class='activity'>
                          <p class='activity-category'>Submissions</p>
                            <p class='activity-count'>{{ $chat->from->approved_tutorials->count() }}</p></div>
                        <div class='activity'>
                          <p class='activity-category'>Upvotes</p>
                            <p class='activity-count'>{{ $chat->from->votes->count() }}</p></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='popover-footer'>
                        <a href='{{ $chat->from->profile_link }}' class='btn btn-sm btn-select'>Open profile</a>
                        <a href='{{ $chat->from->chat_link }}' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Private Chat</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>">
                    </div>
```

Here is the code I have written to trigger and close the popover. Also I am using the bootstrap popovers here.

```
            var timer;
            $(".user-avatar").popover({
                trigger: "manual",
                animation: false
            })
                .on("mouseenter", function(){
                var self = $(this);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    self.popover("show");
                }, 1000);
            })
                .on("mouseleave", function () {
                clearTimeout(timer);

                $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
            });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                        $(this).popover("hide");
                    }
                }, 30);
            });
```

The issue is I am not able to hide the popover when I mouseenter the thumbnail but directly mouseleave the thumbnail (without mouseleaving the popover).

I want the following behaviour:

Popover show when I mouseenter the thumbnail.
Popover stays open when I mouseenter the popover.
Popover hides when I mouseleave the popover.
Popover hides when I mouseleave the thumbnail (without going to the popover).

I am not able to achieve the last point!

Comment: Why don't you use the native [trigger option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) ?? With hover as value ...

Comment: You should probably set a timer when the mouse leaves the element and clear it when the mouse enters the popover.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set a timer when the mouse leaves the element and clear it when the mouse enters the popover.
Something like this:

```
        var timer;
        $(".user-avatar").popover({
            trigger: "manual",
            animation: false
        }).on("mouseenter", function(){
            $(this).popover("show");
        }).on("mouseleave", function () {
            var self = $(this);
            timer = setTimeout(function(){ // You may want to keep a reference to the time of each element.
                self.popover("hide");
            }, 1000);
        });

        $(".popover").on("mouseenter", function(){
            clearTimer(timer);
        }).on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).popover("hide"); // I'm not sure this will work, you may have to keep a reference to the element that owns this popover.
        });
```